# How to get data from Firestore document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'Skate' is it possible to get all data from her document? for example as in the photo the data of the two parks

```
fireStore.collection("Parks").document("PracasGravatai").collection("Skate").document().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String endereco = documentSnapshot.getString("Endereco");
                        String nome = documentSnapshot.getString("Nome");
                        Log.i("LOG: ",endereco);
                        Log.i("LOG",nome);

                        textView.setText("Nome: "+nome+ "Endereço: "+endereco);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection contains documents. Right now you call `document()`, which means that you're creating a reference to a new, empty document. So the `get()` call after that then returns a snapshot to a non-existing document.

To load a specific document, you'll need to know its ID. Once you do, you can load it by calling `get` on the `DocumentReference`:

```
fireStore.collection("Parks").document("PracasGravatai")
         .collection("Skate").document("theIdOfTheDocument").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
```

If you want to load all documents in the `Skate` collection for `PracasGravatai`, you can do so by calling `get` on the collection:

```
fireStore.collection("Parks").document("PracasGravatai")
         .collection("Skate").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Both of these cases are covered in the Firebase documentation on [getting data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).